# Why is my tooltip not triggering? (general eventbinding functionality)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have a simple button element

On this element I bind two events via the following functions:

```
function bindButtonEvent(){
   $(button).off().click(function(){
      //Do stuff
   })
}
```

After this I bind a bootstrap tooltip event via:

```
$(button).tooltip()
```

This does not work, unless I add "click" as parameter to the Off function or do not call bindButtonEvent at all.

This seems logical to me if I bind the tooltip event first. 
But I bind this after calling off. So why does the tooltip still not work then?

Edit:
I Call the bind method (and the other one) onload:

```
$(function () {
    bindButtonEvent();
     $(button).tooltip()
});
```

Here is the HTML button:

```
<button data-id="2" single-document class="btnDocDelete btn btn-remove-icon btn-xs" title="Verwijderen"></button>
```

This is the code of bindButtonEvent: (now with the "click" param)

```
$(".btnDocDelete").off("click").click(function (el) {
            bootbox.confirm({
                title: "Document verwijderen",
                message: "Weet u zeker dat u dit document wilt verwijderen?",
                buttons: {
                    cancel: {
                        label: "Nee",
                        className: "btn-bootbox-cancel"
                    },
                    confirm: {
                        label: "Ja",
                        className: "btn-bootbox-confirm"
                    }
                },
                callback(result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $.post(Site.router.controller.removeDocument(),
                            {
                                id: parseInt(this.data("id"), 10)
                            },
                            data => {
                                if (data.RefresTabs) {
                                    refreshTab(+el.parents("[formtabblad]").attr("formtabblad"), true);
                                    var extraTabsToRefresh = el.parents("[staticblok]").attr("extra-tabs-refresh");
                                    var arr = extraTabsToRefresh.split(",");
                                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                                        refreshTab(+arr[i], false);
                                    }
                                    toastr.success("Document is verwijderd.");
                                } else {
                                    toastr.error(
                                        "Er is helaas iets misgegaan met het verwijderen van het document.");
                                }
                            }

                        );
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You need to show us more code for us to be able to figure out what is wrong. Where do you call your bindButtonEvent-function? What is your scope? How does your html look like?

Comment: I specifically wanted to filter relevant logic, but I added HTML, function call and function implementation now